# IOS smooth skin How to Blur an image while preserving edges?

Tags: iphone, ios, blur, skin, smoothing

sorry for my english im french

How to Blur an image while preserving edges for a smooth and soft skin? i have tried gaussian blur but it "blur everything" no matter what detail exists

I'm looking for a surface blur or a bilateral filter or equivalent

there is a free app on apple store "[morebeaute2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/morebeaute2/id347331305?mt=8)" you can see the filter im talking about, how to reproduce it ?

Thx you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

You would blur the entire image and the mask out the parts that should remain sharp. Finding out what parts should remain sharp programmatically is done via a combination of edge detection and blurring the edges. To get a good result you would probably do this in many steps.

If you have an image editor installed that can to blur and edge detection on an image (maybe [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) or [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/)) I would suggest you start there and try to achieve the effect you are looking for by hand before your write any code.

Also, you will find that image quality and the general lighting etc. in each image will have an impact on the results so I would recommend trying to accomplish the effect on a few different images so that you know the difficulty of the task ahead.

(An easier alternative may be to allow the user to "paint the mask" themselves, i.e. painting over their skin and using that as the mask for the blur).